# What iPhone app to lock a child's phone after x hours and which does not require management from parent's phone?

Tags: ios, parental-control

I'm on Android, my child is on iPhone. IOS doesn't allow me to manage my child's phone, I would need to be myself on iOS. However, is there an iOS app that I could install on my child's phone which would lock the phone after x hours?

Presumably, a password would be required to access the app's settings or to uninstall the app.